# How Do I Check For Matching Strings When Using Spacebars?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

this is my code

```
<select id="updOrg">
        {{#each organization}}
          <option id="{{_id}}" {{ifSelected ../user.profile.organization}}>{{name}} </option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
```

in my template helper my code is

```
'ifSelected':function(org){
    console.log(org);
    console.log(this.name);
    var name=this.name;
    if(org === this.name){
      console.log("matched");
      return "selected";
    }  
  }
```

in the console I'm getting

```
TEST
XXX

TEST
TEST
```

the second two strings are matching,but here it is not matching in the if condition

and I also I can't see `matched` in my console.

what is wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it the following way:

```html
<option id="{{_id}}" selected="{{ifSelected ../user.profile.organization}}">{{name}} </option>
```

and change `ifSelected` to return `true` or `false`.

Why `"TEST"` is not equal to `"TEST"` I can't say, because they should be. Sure there aren't some empty spaces at the end of one of them?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but to reply `true` or `false` first it need to pass the condition, the condition is still not working. I'm sure both "test" are same bcz I'm getting those values from the DB

Comment: @user1934044, what is logging if you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(org))` and  `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.name))` instead?

Comment: Yeah, that shows the space at the rear in ones string, thnakyou very much for the help